# Scrolling in overlay on Mobile Safari scrolls the content behind the overlay

Tags: html, ios, css, mobile-safari

I'm trying to create an overlay with scrollable content. The problem is that on my iPhone I can't always scroll in the overlay, but instead the content behind is scrolled. This problem can be reproduced by clicking in the input field and then clicking open. How can I make sure that the overlay will be scrolled when it's open?

Here's a fiddle with my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/czpkfwwh/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            #overlay {
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: yellow;
                overflow-y: scroll;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            }

            #overlay.active {
                display: block;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" />
        <button id="open">BUTTON</button>
        <div id="overlay">
            <button id="close">CLOSE</button><br />
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                for(var i = 1; i <= 200; i++)
                    $('#overlay').append(i + '<br />');

                $('button').click(function () { $('#overlay').toggleClass('active'); });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```